# OpenVPN don't start: --cert fails with 'client.crt': No such file or directory

Tags: openvpn, vps, openvz

I have a VPS Server running with openVZ and CentOs 6 and I want to install openVPN on it. I followed this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-6 but I'm not able to start the openVPN service:

```
Starting openvpn:                                          [FAILED]
```

Thats is whats inside my `/var/log/messages/` file:

```
Mar  9 10:50:50 s18194633 openvpn[19715]: event_wait : Interrupted system call (code=4)
Mar  9 10:50:50 s18194633 openvpn[19715]: /sbin/ip route del 10.8.0.0/24
Mar  9 10:50:50 s18194633 openvpn[19715]: ERROR: Linux route delete command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Mar  9 10:50:50 s18194633 openvpn[19715]: Closing TUN/TAP interface
Mar  9 10:50:50 s18194633 openvpn[19715]: /sbin/ip addr del dev tun0 local 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2
Mar  9 10:50:50 s18194633 openvpn[19715]: Linux ip addr del failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Mar  9 10:50:50 s18194633 openvpn[19715]: SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19753]: Options error: --cert fails with 'client.crt': No such file or directory
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19753]: Options error: --key fails with 'client.key': No such file or directory
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19753]: Options error: Please correct these errors.
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19753]: Use --help for more information.
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19756]: OpenVPN 2.3.6 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Dec  2 2014
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19756]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013, LZO 2.03
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19756]: Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19756]: Socket Buffers: R=[133120->131072] S=[133120->131072]
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19756]: ROUTE_GATEWAY ON_LINK IFACE=venet0 HWADDR=00:00:00:00:00:00
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19756]: TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19756]: TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19756]: do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19756]: /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19756]: /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19756]: /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19764]: GID set to nobody
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19764]: UID set to nobody
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19764]: UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19764]: UDPv4 link remote: [undef]
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19764]: MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19764]: IFCONFIG POOL: base=10.8.0.4 size=62, ipv6=0
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19764]: IFCONFIG POOL LIST
Mar  9 10:50:52 s18194633 openvpn[19764]: Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Do I have forgotten to do something?

The log says that it can't find `client.crt` and `client.key` but they are in the `/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/`folder

Also, if I do `sysctl -p` I get this error:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
error: "net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables" is an unknown key
error: "net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables" is an unknown key
error: "net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables" is an unknown key
```

Doing `sysctl -e -p` seems to work, but I don't know if this fixes these errors. Can this have something to do with the error when I want to start openVPN?

Didn't this should create those missing files? Or am I missing something else?

This is my `/etc/openvpn/server.conf`:

```
#################################################
# Sample OpenVPN 2.0 config file for            #
# multi-client server.                          #
#                                               #
# This file is for the server side              #
# of a many-clients <-> one-server              #
# OpenVPN configuration.                        #
#                                               #
# OpenVPN also supports                         #
# single-machine <-> single-machine             #
# configurations (See the Examples page         #
# on the web site for more info).               #
#                                               #
# This config should work on Windows            #
# or Linux/BSD systems.  Remember on            #
# Windows to quote pathnames and use            #
# double backslashes, e.g.:                     #
# "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\foo.key" #
#                                               #
# Comments are preceded with '#' or ';'         #
#################################################

# Which local IP address should OpenVPN
# listen on? (optional)
;local a.b.c.d

# Which TCP/UDP port should OpenVPN listen on?
# If you want to run multiple OpenVPN instances
# on the same machine, use a different port
# number for each one.  You will need to
# open up this port on your firewall.
port 1194

# TCP or UDP server?
;proto tcp
proto udp

# "dev tun" will create a routed IP tunnel,
# "dev tap" will create an ethernet tunnel.
# Use "dev tap0" if you are ethernet bridging
# and have precreated a tap0 virtual interface
# and bridged it with your ethernet interface.
# If you want to control access policies
# over the VPN, you must create firewall
# rules for the the TUN/TAP interface.
# On non-Windows systems, you can give
# an explicit unit number, such as tun0.
# On Windows, use "dev-node" for this.
# On most systems, the VPN will not function
# unless you partially or fully disable
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
;dev tap
dev tun

# Windows needs the TAP-Win32 adapter name
# from the Network Connections panel if you
# have more than one.  On XP SP2 or higher,
# you may need to selectively disable the
# Windows firewall for the TAP adapter.
# Non-Windows systems usually don't need this.
;dev-node MyTap

# SSL/TLS root certificate (ca), certificate
# (cert), and private key (key).  Each client
# and the server must have their own cert and
# key file.  The server and all clients will
# use the same ca file.
#
# See the "easy-rsa" directory for a series
# of scripts for generating RSA certificates
# and private keys.  Remember to use
# a unique Common Name for the server
# and each of the client certificates.
#
# Any X509 key management system can be used.
# OpenVPN can also use a PKCS #12 formatted key file
# (see "pkcs12" directive in man page).
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret

# Diffie hellman parameters.
# Generate your own with:
#   openssl dhparam -out dh2048.pem 2048
dh dh2048.pem

# Network topology
# Should be subnet (addressing via IP)
# unless Windows clients v2.0.9 and lower have to
# be supported (then net30, i.e. a /30 per client)
# Defaults to net30 (not recommended)
;topology subnet

# Configure server mode and supply a VPN subnet
# for OpenVPN to draw client addresses from.
# The server will take 10.8.0.1 for itself,
# the rest will be made available to clients.
# Each client will be able to reach the server
# on 10.8.0.1. Comment this line out if you are
# ethernet bridging. See the man page for more info.
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

# Maintain a record of client <-> virtual IP address
# associations in this file.  If OpenVPN goes down or
# is restarted, reconnecting clients can be assigned
# the same virtual IP address from the pool that was
# previously assigned.
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

# Configure server mode for ethernet bridging.
# You must first use your OS's bridging capability
# to bridge the TAP interface with the ethernet
# NIC interface.  Then you must manually set the
# IP/netmask on the bridge interface, here we
# assume 10.8.0.4/255.255.255.0.  Finally we
# must set aside an IP range in this subnet
# (start=10.8.0.50 end=10.8.0.100) to allocate
# to connecting clients.  Leave this line commented
# out unless you are ethernet bridging.
;server-bridge 10.8.0.4 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.50 10.8.0.100

# Configure server mode for ethernet bridging
# using a DHCP-proxy, where clients talk
# to the OpenVPN server-side DHCP server
# to receive their IP address allocation
# and DNS server addresses.  You must first use
# your OS's bridging capability to bridge the TAP
# interface with the ethernet NIC interface.
# Note: this mode only works on clients (such as
# Windows), where the client-side TAP adapter is
# bound to a DHCP client.
;server-bridge

# Push routes to the client to allow it
# to reach other private subnets behind
# the server.  Remember that these
# private subnets will also need
# to know to route the OpenVPN client
# address pool (10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0)
# back to the OpenVPN server.
;push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"
;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

# To assign specific IP addresses to specific
# clients or if a connecting client has a private
# subnet behind it that should also have VPN access,
# use the subdirectory "ccd" for client-specific
# configuration files (see man page for more info).

# EXAMPLE: Suppose the client
# having the certificate common name "Thelonious"
# also has a small subnet behind his connecting
# machine, such as 192.168.40.128/255.255.255.248.
# First, uncomment out these lines:
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
# Then create a file ccd/Thelonious with this line:
#   iroute 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
# This will allow Thelonious' private subnet to
# access the VPN.  This example will only work
# if you are routing, not bridging, i.e. you are
# using "dev tun" and "server" directives.

# EXAMPLE: Suppose you want to give
# Thelonious a fixed VPN IP address of 10.9.0.1.
# First uncomment out these lines:
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.252
# Then add this line to ccd/Thelonious:
#   ifconfig-push 10.9.0.1 10.9.0.2

# Suppose that you want to enable different
# firewall access policies for different groups
# of clients.  There are two methods:
# (1) Run multiple OpenVPN daemons, one for each
#     group, and firewall the TUN/TAP interface
#     for each group/daemon appropriately.
# (2) (Advanced) Create a script to dynamically
#     modify the firewall in response to access
#     from different clients.  See man
#     page for more info on learn-address script.
;learn-address ./script

# If enabled, this directive will configure
# all clients to redirect their default
# network gateway through the VPN, causing
# all IP traffic such as web browsing and
# and DNS lookups to go through the VPN
# (The OpenVPN server machine may need to NAT
# or bridge the TUN/TAP interface to the internet
# in order for this to work properly).
;push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

# Certain Windows-specific network settings
# can be pushed to clients, such as DNS
# or WINS server addresses.  CAVEAT:
# http://openvpn.net/faq.html#dhcpcaveats
# The addresses below refer to the public
# DNS servers provided by opendns.com.
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"

# Uncomment this directive to allow different
# clients to be able to "see" each other.
# By default, clients will only see the server.
# To force clients to only see the server, you
# will also need to appropriately firewall the
# server's TUN/TAP interface.
;client-to-client

# Uncomment this directive if multiple clients
# might connect with the same certificate/key
# files or common names.  This is recommended
# only for testing purposes.  For production use,
# each client should have its own certificate/key
# pair.
#
# IF YOU HAVE NOT GENERATED INDIVIDUAL
# CERTIFICATE/KEY PAIRS FOR EACH CLIENT,
# EACH HAVING ITS OWN UNIQUE "COMMON NAME",
# UNCOMMENT THIS LINE OUT.
;duplicate-cn

# The keepalive directive causes ping-like
# messages to be sent back and forth over
# the link so that each side knows when
# the other side has gone down.
# Ping every 10 seconds, assume that remote
# peer is down if no ping received during
# a 120 second time period.
keepalive 10 120

# For extra security beyond that provided
# by SSL/TLS, create an "HMAC firewall"
# to help block DoS attacks and UDP port flooding.
#
# Generate with:
#   openvpn --genkey --secret ta.key
#
# The server and each client must have
# a copy of this key.
# The second parameter should be '0'
# on the server and '1' on the clients.
;tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret

# Select a cryptographic cipher.
# This config item must be copied to
# the client config file as well.
;cipher BF-CBC        # Blowfish (default)
;cipher AES-128-CBC   # AES
;cipher DES-EDE3-CBC  # Triple-DES

# Enable compression on the VPN link.
# If you enable it here, you must also
# enable it in the client config file.
comp-lzo

# The maximum number of concurrently connected
# clients we want to allow.
;max-clients 100

# It's a good idea to reduce the OpenVPN
# daemon's privileges after initialization.
#
# You can uncomment this out on
# non-Windows systems.
user nobody
group nobody

# The persist options will try to avoid
# accessing certain resources on restart
# that may no longer be accessible because
# of the privilege downgrade.
persist-key
persist-tun

# Output a short status file showing
# current connections, truncated
# and rewritten every minute.
status openvpn-status.log

# By default, log messages will go to the syslog (or
# on Windows, if running as a service, they will go to
# the "\Program Files\OpenVPN\log" directory).
# Use log or log-append to override this default.
# "log" will truncate the log file on OpenVPN startup,
# while "log-append" will append to it.  Use one
# or the other (but not both).
;log         openvpn.log
;log-append  openvpn.log

# Set the appropriate level of log
# file verbosity.
#
# 0 is silent, except for fatal errors
# 4 is reasonable for general usage
# 5 and 6 can help to debug connection problems
# 9 is extremely verbose
verb 3

# Silence repeating messages.  At most 20
# sequential messages of the same message
# category will be output to the log.
;mute 20
```

Thats the output from `ls -la /etc/openvpn`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 root    root   4096  9. Mär 10:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 80 root    root   4096  9. Mär 12:44 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root   1781  9. Mär 10:10 ca.crt
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root   3441 17. Feb 21:55 client.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root   3441 17. Feb 21:55 client.ovpn
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root    424  9. Mär 10:10 dh2048.pem
drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root   4096  9. Mär 10:33 easy-rsa
drwxrwxr-x  3 openvpn games  4096 17. Feb 21:48 EasyRSA-2.2.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root  10492 11. Nov 2013  EasyRSA-2.2.2.tgz
-rw-------  1 root    root      0 17. Feb 22:02 ipp.txt
-rw-------  1 root    root    232  9. Mär 13:01 openvpn-status.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root  10542  9. Mär 09:32 server.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root   5576  9. Mär 10:10 server.crt
-rw-------  1 root    root   1708  9. Mär 10:10 server.key
-rw-------  1 root    root    636  9. Mär 10:50 static.key
```

Comment: `build-key` creates the certificates. Have you followed all the steps in that document under the section "Configuring OpenVPN Client"?

Comment: No, I stopped after `service openvpn start` failed. Does it makes sense to start configuration of the client if the server can't even start?

Comment: I also added another error I get to my description.

Comment: There should be no reference to the client certificates on the server.

Comment: Okay, so I need to move the files `client.crt`, `client.csr` and `client.key` to the client and delete them from the server? But how do I delete the reference?

Comment: It's hard to say without you adding your server config to the question.

Comment: I added my `server.conf`. I hope it helps.

Comment: It does, because it makes me suspect that that's not the config file that's being used.  Can we see if there are any other config files hanging around, ie `ls -la /etc/openvpn`?

Comment: I added `ls -la /etc/openvpn` output and there is a `client.conf`. Do I have to delete it?

Comment: Rename for now it so it has a different extension, perhaps `client.conf.unused`

Comment: Thanks, after I renamed the file I was able to start openVPN. You can post this comment as answer and I accept it if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the service startup file for CentOS will try to run **any** config file that's in `/etc/openvpn` - after all, it has no way of knowing which was the intended config file.

Delete the `client.conf` file that's hanging around in that directory, or as raoima suggests move it to one side, and the openvpn startup script will stop trying to invoke it.

Answer (score 6):

Use absolute path to point where each certificate/key is:

```
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh2048.pem
```

You can also start the OpenVPN server invoking it's own binary.

```
openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf --daemon
```

As roaima said, you must change the extension of your "client.conf" and any other "*.conf" file before using the CentOS startup script.

Answer (score 2):

If you have this problem on **Windows**, like Windows 10, you'll want to do the Windows-equivalent of the other suggestions here.  So, place your `.crt` files into a folder in...

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\OpenVPN\config\*
```

Once the `*.crt` and `.ovpn` files are located here, run OpenVPN through the OpenVPN GUI, loading up your `.ovpn` file and connecting to the VPN -- hopefully!